Black & white Astro Boy episode in which Astro Boy must bury someone
Looking for a specific Astro Boy episode from the black and white series that aired in the USA.
I believe the premise is, Astro Boy must bury someone, perhaps a female colleague? In the end, he walks off into the distance, while a tree grows and a storm rages around him.
I have both the DVD box sets, but have been unable to determine. Can anyone help?
